# Split Common SASS styles in to one css chunk in React instead of duplicated CSS

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, optimization, sass

In CRA React App, I have a common style guide in `SCSS` which is imported in module level scss files using `@use`, using dart SASS as well.

I have changed the references from `@import` to `@use` and was expecting Webpack will handle as common code, will create a separate chunk

**Problem**

How to make one common chunk for a common style guide.

**Screenshots**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved by `Extract Text Plugin`, which...

> Extracts text from a bundle, or bundles, into a separate file. For more [check this](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/mini-css-extract-plugin/).

```
const path = require("path");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    foo: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/foo"),
    bar: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/bar"),
  },
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        fooStyles: {
          type: "css/mini-extract",
          name: "styles_foo",
          chunks: (chunk) => {
            return chunk.name === "foo";
          },
          enforce: true,
        },
        barStyles: {
          type: "css/mini-extract",
          name: "styles_bar",
          chunks: (chunk) => {
            return chunk.name === "bar";
          },
          enforce: true,
        },
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "[name].css",
    }),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader"],
      },
    ],
  },
}
```

Though, I'm not sure if you're looking for the above one or another plug-in called `CommonsChunkPlugin`, which acts similar.

> The [CommonsChunkPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/commons-chunk-plugin/) is an opt-in feature that creates a separate file (known as a chunk), consisting of common modules shared between multiple entry points.

Example:

```
new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
  name: 'app',
  // or
  names: ['app', 'subPageA'],
  // the name or list of names must match the name or names
  // of the entry points that create the async chunks

  children: true,  // use all children of the chunk
  async: true,
  minChunks: 3,  // 3 children must share the module before it's separated
})
```

Comment: I think react CRA already uses it, I am not sure even if using `@use` why common stylesheet is repeated in every chunk

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing `src` in your images, which tells me that those screen captures you took is in development, not production.

In development webpack should use `style-loader` and directly load all styles and inject it into the DOM using style tags to speed up development.  So seeing multiple files is normal in development.

In production webpack should use something like `mini-css-extract-plugin` and compile all your sass to a single css file.

The only way to get multiple css files in webpack for production is to create multiple entries for each file.

Comment: Thanks For the Reply!
 I have added Route based code splitting as well, that might be the reason for multiple CSS files.  The challenge I have is if I am using `@use` for referencing sass files why the same stylesheet is duplicated in multiple chunk

Comment: Try using https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass instead of dart-sass, perhaps it's an issue with their package.  However I don't believe it has anything to do with routes or code splitting, I've never seen that before.  Likely only an issue with ````@use```` itself and it seems ````sass```` is the only one that isn't giving a lot of issues with it.